# How can I view the links at the bottom of my Facebook feed?

Tags: facebook

Facebook has several links, like "About" at the bottom of the page. But when I try to scroll down to them, more posts load before I can read/click them.

How can I view these links?

Comment: Another annoying thing about this is that sometimes when you've scrolled to the bottom of the "viewable portion" of the Home Page/Timelines, once the older New Feeds start to load, the scroll function is so touchy that it throws me way off from where I was. (I hope that made sense.. I have a hard time explaining these things with words...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the *Privacy Settings* page and scroll down.

[image]